# Does EntityScanner detect abstract classes and interfaces? (Spring Boot 2.2.6)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Does the `EntityScanner` detect abstract classes or interfaces that are annotated with the specific annotation type the scanner is looking for? In my Spring Boot application I use an `EntityScanner` instance to find all classes that have a certain annotation (eg. `@MyAnnotationType`). However, it doesn't detect abstract classes or interfaces with that annotation:

```
@MyAnnotationType
public interface Foo
```

When I call `Set<Class<?>> entityClassSet = entityScanner.scan(MyAnnotationType.class)` the `Foo` interface is not included in the returned `entityClassSet`. The same thing happens to abstract classes with the `@MyAnnotationType` annotation. Note that all the classes are in the subpackage of the `@SpringBootApplication` classes package. Is this expected behaviour? If so, is there an alternative to `EntityScanner` that I can use to detect these abstract classes/interfaces? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

No it does not. `EntityScanner` is meant to detect classes only. Looking at the implementation of `EntityScanner`, you can see it uses `ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider` under the hood.

If you need to scan for abstract classes or interfaces, you could use that. When doing so, you'll have to override `isCandidateComponent`.

Comment: Thanks Stephane. I ended up extending the C...ComponentProvider but I had to duplicate the EntityScanner entirely (final and private methods didn't allow for reuse). [Here's how it ended up](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/pull/839/files#diff-7c0ec5850b63c5b1b04bdfbafbfd8d46R304).